# Which imperial units of measurement use vulgar (simple) fraction numbers?

Tags: measurements

All values of metric units are expressed in decimal or scientific notation. Some imperial units, use fraction numbers as primary notation (3/4" for 0.75 inch).
As far as i know, only inch and foot values are using this notation. Are there any other units using this notation?

**Update**

- My question is about the *written* form
- IMO it is not about language but more engineering related. To be more specific: the background of my question is about how to store those notations in digital form (so maybe ask this at stackoverflow?). In other words: what data type should be used for number values of specific units of measurement. Millimeters can always be stored as decimal. For inches this is weird, and a fraction number is expected.
- We have a system, used to store a lot of technical data (characteristics of technical components). We are wondering if the data type should be dependent on the System of Measurement used, imperial or metric:

  - metric: data type = decimal
  - imperial: data type = fraction **BIG question**: for inch and ???

Comment: Now that the question has been clarified, I cleaned the comments.

Comment: If it's about **engineering related**, then it is hard to get away from the decimals or the metric system (apologies to the Americans that read this).

Comment: We use the SI in electrical engineering so the question is moot for us. Even in 'murica.

Comment: The use of fractions is mainly a communications issue.  Easier for us brought up on imperial system to visualize.  Store your imperial data as decimals.  If you want to use your data, say to compare numbers, you'd have to do calculations (7/64 vs 7/8).